# Is it possible to use a lambda to trigger a stored procedure in snowflake?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sdk, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know that snowflake allows you to get files directly from an S3.
But what I'm trying is to use a lambda that gets those csvs and put them into snowflake.

I can't find much doc on this and the snowflake-sdk is not very clear on this.

I was able to connect to snowflake using my lambda and the sdk, but I'm not sure if my lambda can do something else such as invoke a stored procedure.

Thanks

Comment: If you can invoke a stored procedure in a programmatic way from outside of Lambda (can you?) then you can do it from within a Lambda function (networking access required, of course).

Comment: That´s the thing, I don´t think I can invoke a store procedure outside snowflake, at least, I can´t find the doc for it.

Comment: Something like [*this*](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Use-Snowflake-with-AWS-Lambda) would help?

Comment: That actually would, I mean, the sql can be anything, even a store procedure. I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: For sure - but can you explain why a lambda? What's the flow you are looking for?

Comment: So what I've been asked to do is: a Lambda that gets triggered when there is a change on an s3, gets the csv and puts it into a snowflake DB.

Comment: @MarioGarcia if you're just loading data that has landed into S3 you should use snowpipe. There is a way to automate the load once a file is in s3, doco here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html